# Oracle Managed ODP.NET: Connection is forcibly closed due to network error

Tags: c#, .net, database, oracle, odp.net

I use `Oracle` `ODP.NET` connector to connect to `Oracle` database server.

The problem is a connection sometimes is lost due to several different problems (like network failure or server forcibly closes a connetion by peer).
This causes an uncaught exception because I cannot catch exceptions while a connection object is not used in a query or during an idle time of an application.

The question is how can I catch `Oracle` connection exceptions when a connection is lost?
Is there any callback technique or something that can inform me about disconnection?

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about why you need this? You are not using the connection anyway and as soon as you try to you will know there is a problem.

Comment: A single connection object is used at many places in my application. I want to be sure the connection is valid when it is used. I have to edit a lot of lines of codes so that to catch and to fix the disconnection (I will do so if there is no ohter way to go). So, I want to intercept the disconnection exception and to try to restore the connection again so that other places (where a connection object is used) even do not notice that the disconnection happened a second ago. What does exactly happen when a disconnection occur? What state a connection object gets when a connection is broken?

Comment: Can you simply return the connection to the OracleConnection connection pool after you have used it, and get another one when you need it? It is easy to configure the connection pool to make sure the connection it dispenses is always valid. (use Validate Connection=true) http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10927_01/featConnecting.htm

Comment: Your problem is fundamentally caused by reusing a single connection object over and over.  You should create each connection object in a using statement so it gets disposed as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment above about Validate Connection = true in the connection pool connect string.

You can also write your own "connection tester" routine that does a "Select sysdate from dual" against the database to test the connection.

Both of these solutions cost a roundtrip to the database. Neither of these solutions completely prevent network errors as they can happen right after you test it.

Bottom line is you need to be catching exceptions anytime you use an ODP.NET object if you don't want an unhandled exception.

There's no callback mechanism available that will prevent this.

I don't really understand how you seem to be saying you are getting exceptions when you are not using the odp.net objects. If you are getting an exception, you must be using the odp.net object at that moment and therefore you can catch the exception in that code.